# How to add a custom colorful Image to a tabBar in a TabBarController?

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I am using a UITabBarController where i want to load a custom colorful image to the respective TabBar. I want to customize the font size,color and type of the Text for the UITabBar item. I have tried out many possibilities by using image property for the tabBar and tried to create a imageview and adding it as an subview to the tabBar. Can someone please provide any alternative to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way for this is implementing your own custom tab bar controller. You can find many tutorial on the web if you google "custom tab bar". [This is one](http://www.hollance.com/2011/11/mhtabbarcontroller-a-custom-tab-bar-for-ios-5-using-the-new-container-apis/) for iOS 5. And [here](http://rocksaucestudios.com/tapsauce/post/ios-custom-tab-bar/), you can find another.

Comment: Is it accepted to subclass the UITabBar class? I mean will Apple reject the application incase the UITabBar class is subclassed?

Comment: I don't think Apple will reject an app that subclasses `UITabBar`, but the point is: you don't need to subclass `UITabBar` to create a custom tab bar controller. have a look at the tutorials...